# PopupMenu error when trying to show

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, popupmenu

I'm having a strange problem with a popup menu (it's not the first time I'm using in my code so I don't understand why it happens).

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
```

This is the code to show the PopupMenu:

```
        PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu();
        p.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Delete gear", Id = 0 });
        p.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "-", Id = 1 });

        if (index != 0)     // If first elem, don't show this part
        {
        p.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Bring to top", Id = 2 });
        p.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Bring up", Id = 3 });
        }
        if (index != GearTree[0].GearGroup.Count - 1)   // If last elem, don't show this part
        {
        p.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Bring down", Id = 4 });
        p.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Bring to bottom", Id = 5 });
        }


        // TODO: here happens the ERROR, posibly in new Point(0,0) part
        IUICommand selection = await p.ShowAsync(new Point(0, 0));
```